# how to get rootviewcontroller ios storyboard

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I have a menu table in the root view of a storyboard that I want reloaded whenever a sub view updates data.  How do I get a reference to the root view so that I can call the reloaddata method on it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can access it using the below code if the `rootViewController` is a `UIViewController`

```
UIViewController *rootController=(UIViewController *)((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).window.rootViewController;
```

But if it's a `UINavigationController` you can use the code below.

```
UINavigationController *nav=(UINavigationController *)((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).window.rootViewController;
UIViewController *rootController=(UIViewController *)[nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift:**

`let rootVC = self.window?.rootViewController`

Comment: What is `self` in this context?

Comment: let rootVC = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController

Comment: sorry was simply there AppDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

From the console:

`po [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController]
<UINavigationController: 0x15f076c00>`